# ios arc UILabel.text memory increase constantly

Tags: ios, memory, label, automatic-ref-counting

I use **ARC**.
I find the memory increase constantly.

in .h file

```
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel* contentALabel;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel* contentBLabel;
```

in .m file

```
-(void)refreshContent:(NSInteger) itemID
{
    sqlite3 *database;

    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *docsPath = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString* databasePath = [docsPath stringByAppendingPathComponent: @"Database.sqlite"];
    if(sqlite3_open([databasePath UTF8String], &database) == SQLITE_OK) {

        NSString  *sql = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"select contentA,contentB from tableA where  itemID = %d ",itemID,nil];

        char *sqlStatement = (char *)[sql cStringUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
        sqlite3_stmt *compiledStatement;

        if(sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, sqlStatement, -1, &compiledStatement, NULL) == SQLITE_OK) {

            while(sqlite3_step(compiledStatement) == SQLITE_ROW) {

                NSString *contentA = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(compiledStatement, 0)];
                NSString *contentB = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(compiledStatement, 1)];

                contentALabel.text = contentA;
                contentBLabel.text = contentB;
            }
        }

        sqlite3_finalize(compiledStatement);
    }
    sqlite3_close(database);
}
```

I call this function constantly , I find my **memory increase** as well in the 'Profile' window 'Living Bytes' column.

but if I comment

```
contentALabel.text = contentA;
contentBLabel.text = contentB;
```

the memory won't increase any more.

What's wrong with the '**Label.text**' ?

Comment: There's no problem with `label.text` except that it maintains a strong reference to your `NSString` (but it should release the previous value when you set the new value). Are you possibly creating new `contentALabel` and `contentBLabel` objects, without doing `removeFromSuperview` on the old ones?

Comment: I encountered the same problem. described here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16495240/if-uilabel-text-different-chinese-strings-memory-leak

Comment: Did your content contains multibytes characters?

Answer (score 0):

Bottom line, setting the `text` property for a `UILabel` would not explain this behavior. I'd be inclined to run through the battery of suggestions covered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14105056/1271826). Specifically, look for leaks and if you don't find any, use the allocations tool to identify what's being created (and obviously not released). I'd also put in a breakpoint and then type "`po [[UIWindow keyWindow] recursiveDescription]`" into the debugger and make sure you're not getting additional views/controls added to your window hierarchy.

I know this isn't going to feel like a satisfactory answer, but you're just going to have to spend a little time in Instruments, looking for leaks, and if not apparent, just identifying the allocations that are obviously not getting released.