# What are the best practices to avoid leaks when using objective-c blocks?

Tags: ios, objective-c, memory-management, memory-leaks, objective-c-blocks

I have been working with blocks for a while and I'm trying to be aware of all leaking possible scenarios. I have read a lot about the "retain cycle loop", but I think that maybe there are other possible scenarios. Also, I'm thinking in some simple cases, like: What if you call a block inside a block?; Is different the block memory management if we use ARC or not?; how to find if a block is leaking memory with instruments (or some other tool)?.

Comment: You specially have to worry when you capture self : http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/WorkingwithBlocks/WorkingwithBlocks.html

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Short answer: Blocks don't inherently introduce any special leak issues (other than retain cycles in special circumstances, described below).

Long answer: A couple of thoughts:

1. Other than retain cycles (also known as strong reference cycles in ARC) caused if you fail to [Avoid Strong Reference Cycles when Capturing self](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/WorkingwithBlocks/WorkingwithBlocks.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011210-CH8-SW16)), there really aren't other special leaking risks associated with blocks. If you remember that blocks maintain strong references to objects they reference, then just follow the standard [basic rules of memory management](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/mmRules.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000994-SW1).

   As discussed in the [Use Lifetime Qualifiers to Avoid Strong Reference Cycles](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/releasenotes/ObjectiveC/RN-TransitioningToARC/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011226-CH1-SW4), in MRC you can use the `__block` qualifier to solve these strong reference cycles, but in ARC, you can use the `__weak` qualifier.
2. If you're putting blocks in blocks, that's doesn't introduce any additional leak risks (unless you concoct some circular set of references that causes a strong reference cycle, which is generally unlikely when doing blocks within blocks).
3. The blocks retain the objects they reference (unless the object is qualified, such as with `__block` in MRC or with `__weak` in ARC). The fact that one uses blocks has no bearing on whether the code leaks or not. That's a function of your choice of ARC v MRC and whether you've avoided retain cycles and, if doing MRC, whether you've included the necessary `release` statements.
4. In terms of finding leaks, the standard tools all work fine:

   - Especially if doing non-ARC code, the static analyzer (<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>command</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd> or choose "Analyze" from the "Product" menu) is very useful.
   - The [Finding Leaks in Your App](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/developertools/Conceptual/InstrumentsUserGuide/MemoryManagementforYouriOSApp/MemoryManagementforYouriOSApp.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40004652-CH11-SW4) discussion in the *Instruments User Guide*.
   - Sometimes for strong reference cycles, it won't always be flagged by the Leaks tool in instruments. At that point, it's sometimes useful to use the Allocations tool in Instruments, highlight some allocation that you suspect should have been freed but wasn't, and it will show you what allocated that memory. See [iOS app with ARC, find who is owner of an object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14104556/ios-app-with-arc-find-who-is-owner-of-an-object/14105056#14105056)
   - If you're wondering if some object is being deallocated properly, it's useful to add a diagnostic `dealloc` implementation to your object that should be released:

     ```
     - (void)dealloc
     {
         NSLog(@"%s", __FUNCTION__);

         // if non-ARC, remember to include the following line, too:
         //
         // [super dealloc];
     }
     ```

     That way, you'll see a message on your console when the object is deallocated.
5. If you're worried about leaks, using ARC is (IMHO) one of the easiest way to eliminate many mundane leaks. It's incredibly easy to leak in non-ARC code with a simple omitted `release` or `autorelease` (though, admittedly, the above links will help you find them). It's much harder to leak in ARC because of a simple "oh, I forgot to `release`."

#### References

- [Blocks Programming Topics](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/conceptual/Blocks/Articles/00_Introduction.html)
- [Working with Blocks](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/WorkingwithBlocks/WorkingwithBlocks.html) section of the *Programming with Objective-C* guide
- The [Advanced Memory Management Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/MemoryMgmt.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000011-SW1)
- [Transitioning to ARC Release Notes](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#releasenotes/ObjectiveC/RN-TransitioningToARC/Introduction/Introduction.html)

Comment: "is not noticeably different in ARC v non-ARC" For one thing, the memory management of `__block` variables differ between MRC and ARC

Comment: @LuisEspinoza: In ARC, `__block` variables of object pointer type are automatically retained by the block. However, in MRC, `__block` variables of object pointer type are not automatically retained.

Comment: @newacct Agreed. That's not the point I was trying to convey, but I can see how it could easily be read that way and I've tried to clarify.