# Using the debugger to find all strong references to an object

Tags: ios, objective-c, automatic-ref-counting, dealloc, xcode-instruments

I have an object a1 of class A, I want to find all the objects that hold a strong a reference to the object a1.

Is there a way to do it?

The reason I want to know this is because, a1 doesn't seem to be deallocated.

Comment: See the latter part of [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14105056/1271826), which shows the "Record reference counts" feature, which helps identify all strong references.

Comment: Thanks a lot !! Could you pls post that as an answer so that I can mark it as answered. Awesome, Under Allocation List the column category corresponds to the object.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, using Instruments.app, you can. [Apple has a simple introduction](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/InstrumentsUserGuide/MemoryManagementforYouriOSApp/MemoryManagementforYouriOSApp.html), and if that doesn't help, many others have tutorials for using Instruments as well.

---

edit - [this article](https://www.technetexperts.com/mobile/identify-memory-leaks-during-ios-app-development-using-instruments-with-xcode/) looks useful, too.

Comment: The link in your answer is broken.

Comment: Links in this answer are broken and no longer helpful.

Comment: Found the article under a different URL, also updated the link in the answer:
https://www.technetexperts.com/mobile/identify-memory-leaks-during-ios-app-development-using-instruments-with-xcode/