# How to release viewControllers that has been launched and killed several times during the day?

Tags: ios, objective-c, memory-management, memory-leaks, automatic-ref-counting

I try to kill some views with that code (and the same on the other way with the other view):

```
NSMutableArray *vcArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray: self.navigationController.viewControllers];
[vcArray removeObjectAtIndex: 0];
self.navigationController.viewControllers = vcArray;
[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"segueOldView" sender:nil];
```

My problem, is that the memory is increasing, and I cannot manage it as it is with ARC.

[image]

Comment: That piece of code you pasted has nothing to do with your memory issues, which are most likely caused by retain cycles. Launch `Leaks` Instrument and search for memory leaks.

Comment: Or (easier, IMHO), use "debug memory graph" feature and identify things in the list that should have been deallocated, and it will show you what established the strong reference to it. See latter part of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14105056/1271826).